# inject several hundred of images into divs

Tags: javascript, html, image

I would like to know how to add several hundred images in divs but automatically. I have a folder with the images and I want to know if there is a technique to avoid copying and pasting the same code.

For example: `<img src="img/01.png">`

the idea is to inject this code into the divs and change the names of the images: 01.png, 02.png, 03.png...

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You should read directory and change file name for each file with PHP (i think in loop) and then display them in divs (in something like gallery i believe). ..

Comment: If you have a list of the images then you can loop over that list and emit code.  Do you have server-side code which can emit a list to the client, perhaps from an AJAX call?  Or if the list is static and you have no server-side code then I imagine you could write it to a JavaScript object once and use that on the page.  It really depends on what kind of code/tools/etc. is available to you.  From in-browser JavaScript directly you can't read a directory on the server.

Comment: thank you for the answers. I work locally on html and css files only. I don't have a server. I want to build a wall of images without rendering on the server side, just want to write my code faster.

Comment: @Nicolas: If all you have is client-side JavaScript then you can't read a server-side directory.  You can still loop over a set of data to generate your HTML, but you'll need that data.  If your file names are guaranteed to follow a specific pattern then you can encode that pattern (such as just an incrementing integer).  If not then you'll need the list of file names in an array in your JavaScript code, which you'd likely need to enter manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate the html using javascript if you run this html page it'll display the  tags for the first 99 images.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Hello</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p id="my_output"></p>
  <script>
    let escapeHTML = function (aValue) {
      return (
        aValue.replace(/>/g, '&gt;').
          replace(/</g, '&lt;').
          replace(/"/g, '&quot;')
      )
    }

    let myOutput = document.querySelector('#my_output')

    for (let i = 1; i < 100; ++i) {
      let paddedIndex = ('0' + i).slice(-2)
      myOutput.innerHTML += escapeHTML('<img src="img/' + paddedIndex + '.png">') + '<br>'
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

You can then copy paste the output into your code.

Comment: Thanks! it's a lot like what I want to do. If I want to change the number of images and make more than a hundred?

Comment: @Nicolas you'll have to update this line let paddedIndex = ('0' + i).slice(-2) maybe with let paddedIndex = ('00' + i).slice(-3) and update the for loop to iterate more than 100 times. If you like the answer accepting it would be much appreciated.

Comment: is it possible to surround the code <img src="1.jpg> with another code and that it increases every 3 digits. 
For example:
<div id="item1"><img src="1.jpg"></div>
<div id="item2"><img src="2.jpg"></div>
<div id="item3"><img src="3.jpg"></div>
<div id="item1"><img src="4.jpg"></div>
<div id="item2"><img src="5.jpg"></div>
<div id="item3"><img src="6.jpg"></div>
etc...

The images increase by +1 but the id of the div it is necessary 1,2,3 then again 1,2,3...

Comment: @Nicolas You wouldn't want to do that because an id should be unique, use class instead. To do it you'll need to use the modulo operator ( % ) something like let classToUse = 3 if ( i % 3 == 0 ) classToUse = 3 else it ( i % 3 == 1 ) classToUse = 1 else classToUse = 2 and then insert it into the string you're building <div class="item' + classToUse + '" ... in this special case I think we can simplify the definition of classToUse as follow: let classToUse = i % 3 if ( classToUse == 0 ) classToUse = 3.

Comment: thank you for your help! I made this with your first code : https://codepen.io/nicolastilly/pen/gZBYKZ but for the rest, I'm a little lost.

Comment: @Nicolas Here's the code with the added div. Remember I put class and not id since you shouldn't have duplicate ids. for (let i = 1; i < 300; ++i) {
              let classToUse = i % 3
       if ( classToUse == 0 )
        classToUse = 3
              myOutput.innerHTML += escapeHTML('<div class="item' + classToUse + '"><img src="img/' + i + '.jpg"></div>') + '<br>'
            }

Comment: merci pour votre aide. J'ai modifié le code. Je pense maintenant qu'il s'agit d'une petite erreur mais je n'arrive pas à la trouver :/ https://codepen.io/nicolastilly/pen/gZBYKZ?editors=1010

Comment: @Nicolas Voilà le code sans les bugs. for (let i = 1; i < 300; ++i) { 
      let classToUse = i % 3; if ( classToUse == 0 ) classToUse = 3;
      myItem.innerHTML += escapeHTML('<div class="item' + classToUse + '"><img src="img/' + i + '.jpg"</div>') + '<br>' 
     }

Comment: Vraiment merci !